# jquery find disabled in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three select boxes:

```
<select id="box1">   
    <option>foo1</option>   
</select>               

<select id="box2">
    <option>foo2</option>
</select>

<select id="box3">
    <option disabled>foo3</option>
</select>
```

I need to get select id of option:disabled -> (box3)

How to find id of option:disabled with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:disabled` pseudo selector to achieve this

```
$('select option:disabled')
```

To get parent element - you can use `closest` selector or `parent`

```js
console.log($('select option:disabled').closest('select').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="box1">       
   <option disabled>foo1</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">       
   <option>foo1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert($('option:disabled').parent().attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="box2">

</select>
<select id="box1">

</select>
<select id="box3">
  <option>foo1</option>
  <option>foo2
  </option>
  <option disabled>foo3</option>
</select>
```

Use selector :disabled

Answer (score 0):

```js
var id = $("option:disabled").closest("select").attr('id');
console.log(id);
```